# iOS: display an image with the same quality for all screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, constraints

My view in the storyboard contains an imageView having for the constraints top= 0, height= 55, width= 230 and centred horizontally. Using the "view as" option in the last version of Xcode, I realise that the display of the image and its quality are not the same for all the screens. In the iPhone 4s the quality is good but the image same big. Otherwise, in the iPhone 6s plus screen, I see that the image size is good for the screen but the quality isn't well.

How the image can be displayed the same way in all the screens? Can anyone please give me the right constraints to resolve this?

Comment: try to set the right content mode for your UIImageView

Comment: @RaduNunu can you please tell me what is the best content mode for this situation?

Comment: there are fews, but i guess you need the AspectToFit or AspectToFill, both are respecting the proportion of your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the device's screen, you should define various representation of the image.

From the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/) portal:

> iOS uses a coordinate system to place content onscreen. This
>   coordinate system is based on measurements in points, which map to
>   pixels in the display.

If you define all three image resolutions (`normal`/`@1x`, `@2x`, `@3x`), you should be good to go.

What is important, that the `normal` or `@1x` should have the following parameters: `height: 55, width: 230`

The `@2x` should be twice the size of `@1x`: `height: 110, width:460`

The `@3x` should be three times the size of `@1x`: `height: 165, width:690`

Lets assume you image is called `my_image`, and it is a png.

- the `@1x` should be called: `my_image.png`
- the `@2x` should be called: `my_image@2x.png`
- the `@3x` should be called: `my_image@3x.png`

Add all these images to the `Assets.xcassets`. Click on `Assets.xcassets`. Once it is opened, you should see a `+` sign on the left hand side.

[image]

Tap on the `+` sign and give a name to you image:

[image]

And insert them into these slots:

[image]

Now, when you are trying to use this image, you can just simply say in Swift:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my_image")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I understand what you said, I must have the same image but with 3 different resolutions (3 copies). And in the code I have to detect the screen size to display the right image (so the right resolution). Isn't it?

Comment: The first part you are right, need 3 different resolutions from the image. However, if you add them to the asset catalog, with the right postfix, than the OS will pick the right one for you. I added a little example to my answer for the naming.

Comment: Thanks for the edit I understand now what I have to do but I have a small problem: I don't have in my project the Images.xcassets. I have only the Assets.xcassets and to be honest I have never used it. Can you guide me please?

Comment: Assets.xcassets is the same. I will add a few screenshots.

Comment: Thank you so much!